# How to calculate loop boundary?

Tags: math

I need to calculate the loop boundary without using loops, i.e. with a single expression.

For example:
`for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i += 3)`

The lower bound is 0, upper bound is 10 - 10 % 3 = 9


How can I calculate bounds in such case?
`for (int i = 17; i >= 7; i -= 6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `for (int i = a; i <= b; i += c)` and assuming `a` ≤ `b` and 0 < `c`, the distance from `a` to `b` is `b-a`, the number of whole  steps of size `c` that fit in that distance is `(b-a)/c` (using integer division, so it truncates), the distance traversed by that many steps is `(b-a)/c*c`, so the final value is `a + (b-a)/c*c`. This assumes there is no overflow in the arithmetic of course, which there may be if `b` is large and `a` is a large negative value.

Similarly, for `for (int i = a; i >= b; i -= c)`, the final value is `a + (a-b)/c*c`.